# Accessibility of accessors error

Tags: c#

I have the following line of code in my program

```
public Chromosome NewChromosome { get; public set; }
```

which gives the following error:

> Error 1
>
> The accessibility modifier of the `'ARP_TLL.DataAccess.ChromosomeAddedEventArgs.NewChromosome.set'` accessor must be more restrictive than the property or indexer `'ARP_TLL.DataAccess.ChromosomeAddedEventArgs.NewChromosome'`
>
> `C:\Users\kiangtengl\Programming\Projects\ARP_TLL\ARP_TLL\DataAccess\ChromosomeAddedEventArgs.cs`
>
> 16
> 55
> ARP_TLL

I have tried modifying the accessibility modifiers of the accessors and the property but I am unable to fix the problem.

For reference, here is the type `Chromosome`

```
public class Chromosome
{
    #region properties

    public int Length
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int Number
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    #endregion

    #region creation

    public static Chromosome CreateChromosome(int _length, int _number)
    {
        return new Chromosome
        {
            Length = _length, Number = _number, 
        };
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `public` from `public set` or make it more restrictive than `public`. In

```
[property_access_modifier] property_type property_name {
    [get_accessor_modifier] get;
    [set_accessor_modifier] set;
}
```

it must be that `get_accessor_modifier` and `set_accessor_modifier` are more restrictive than `property_access_modifier`. In your case, `property_access_modifier` is `public` so that `get_accessor_modifier` and `set_accessor_modifier` must be `protected`, `internal`, `protected internal` or `private`.

Keep in mind that if `property_access_modifier` is omitted then it defaults to `private` and `get_accessor_modifier` and `set_accessor_modifier` default to `property_access_modifier` if they are omitted.

Answer (score 5):

Drop the `public` access modifier on the setter:

```
public Chromosome NewChromosome { get; set; }
```

By default, access modifiers for a property's accessors are assigned the same access modifier as the property itself.  If you choose to set an explicit access modifier for an accessor, it must be more restrictive than the property's access modifier.